# Adding a container element to an XML using Python

Tags: python, xml

Here is my code:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 

xml_file = "dummy.xml"
xmlFile = ET.parse(xml_file)

root = xmlFile.getroot() 
root.keys()

newroot = ET.Element("languages")

for child in root:
    if child.tag == "language":
        newroot.insert(1, newroot)
        xmlFile.write("fileName")
    else:
        print "no"
```

This is the original XML file (dummy.xml):

```
<book>
    <title> Everyday Italian </title>
    <author> Giada DeLaurentiis </author>
    <language> English </language>
    <section> Cooking </section>
</book>
```

Here is what I want the new XML (fileName) to look like:

```
<book>
    <title> Everyday Italian </title>
    <author> Giada DeLaurentiis </author>
    <languages>
    <language> English </language>
    </languages>
    <section> Cooking </section>
</book>
```

Please help.  I cannot seem to add the container element "languages" correctly to the new XML file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from xml.dom import minidom
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 

xml_file = "dummy.xml"
xmlFile = ET.parse(xml_file)

root = xmlFile.getroot() 
root.keys()

newroot = ET.Element("languages")

for child in root:
    if child.tag == "language":
        newroot.insert(1, child)
        root.remove(child)
        root.insert(1, newroot)
        xmlFile.write("newdummy.xml")
    else:
        print "no"
```

you need to insert your child to newroot first, then insert newroot to the root.